# Racket : unbound identifier in module in: vector?

Tags: racket

I'm trying to run a program in racket using #lang plai-typed, but I keep getting the 'unbound identifier' errors

```
(define (get-fundef [n : symbol] [fds : (vector FunDefC)]) : FunDefC
  (cond [(empty? fds)
         (error 'get-fundef "reference to undefined function")]
        [(vector? fds)
         (cond [(equal? n (fdC-name (vector-ref fds 0))) (vector-ref fds 0)]
               [else (get-fundef n (vector-drop fds 1))])]))
```

When I run the same with 'listof' instead of 'vector' as input, adjusted to the list type, it works. With vectors I get:

'unbound identifier in module in: vector?'

Help?

Answer (score 1):

`#lang plai-typed` doesn't have a `vector?` function, for the same reason it doesn't have a `list?`, `symbol?`, or `number?` function: you don't need to check type of a value; the type annotations tell you.

If you meant to check whether the vector is empty or not, you could use `(= 0 (vector-length fds))` and `(< 0 (vector-length fds))`.

But why do you want to use vectors? Lists tend to be a lot more convenient:

- There are more utility functions for lists; in particular, `filter` would be helpful here.
- Vectors are less convenient to recur over, since there's no `vector-drop` or `vector-rest` function. If you really want to iterate over a vector, you probably need to use an index.
- Vectors are mutable, which you don't want unless you really need it.

Comment: Just noticed the date on this question; sorry if this is necromancy.